# Object oriented with attribute receiving list within list

Tags: object, oop, orientation

good night guys
A question here about Object Orientation. I have the following return, what would be the best way to create this cluster attribute in Dart, since it is a list inside the.
[
{"centroid":[ 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1],`enter code here`
"cluster":[
[ 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],[ 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1 ],],`enter code here`
"clusterInd":[0]}
] (editado)